# How to copy a File from a subFolder inside resources to another subFolder inside resources of SpringBoot Project

Tags: java, spring, file, copy, resources

I have a Spring Boot Project and inside Resources Folder, I have 2 folders
`src/main/resources/source --> toBeCopied.txt`

and this file needs to be copied to another subFolder inside resources

`src/main/resources/dest --> copied.txt`

So how can I achieve this in Spring, Java??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind use CommonsIO lib. You can try something like:

```
File src = new File("src/main/resources/source/toBeCopied.txt");
File dest = new File("src/main/resources/dest/");
try {
  FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(src, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also before you need make import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

Comment: Thanks @Yevhen Zhovtonoh this apparently helped me, but done little changes to make it work for my use case:

`File dest = new File("src/main/resources/source/toBeCopied.tx");

 File src = new File("src/main/resources/dest/copied.txt");

 FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest);`

This creates a file with given name in proper location.

This doesn't create a extra directory apart from your code that creates a folder with name `toBeCopied.tx` and then creates a new file with name `copied.txt`

Comment: Yes. I've just finished debugging to provide you more appropriate code. I thought that quick answer will be ok. I will correct answer in a minute.

Comment: Your Method is working fine when running on eclipse, but when I trying to make a war or jar file there is a error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'src/main/resources/source/toBeCopied.txt'` does not exist So how to make it work in war or jar packaging!!